# How do increasing tax rate helps control inflation?

Tags: taxation

Also, do the opposite that is lowering tax rate controls deflation?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Answer (score 1):

If the government taxes people but does not spend the money, accumulating surplus, it will decrease aggregate demand. Aggregate demand depends on consumption, which depends on disposable income and taxes reduce disposable income. A decrease in aggregate demand will decrease the price level, reducing inflation or causing deflation, if nothing else happens (see [this](https://www.economicshelp.org/blog/2269/economics/ways-to-reduce-inflation/) article by Pettinger).

Comment: Nice answer but it could be improved with references to sources

Comment: Your first sentence talks about the money supply, but the rest is about the the impact of fiscal policy on the balance between aggregate supply and demand, which is a slightly different issue.  I prefer the second part in response to this question.

Comment: @1muflon1 I added some source

Comment: @Henry I deleted the first sentence but at our university we were taught that fiscal contraction reduces M holdings of households. I know that fiscal and monetary policy are different